# Propositional logic - having trouble translating sentences into statements and deducing information

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I came across an exercise on the Internet which I have had real trouble solving. I have the following text:

> If you know you don't exist, then you don't exist. Obviously, the knowledge that you don't exist is sufficient to deduce that you know something. You exist, unless you don't know anything. Does this imply your existence or your nonexistence? Algebraically prove it.

So this is what I have come up with:

$A$ - I exist, and $B$ - I know something.

1. *"If you know you don't exist, then you don't exist"* - $\overline{A}B \Rightarrow \overline{A}$

This is a simple matter of an implication.

2. *"Obviously, the knowledge that you don't exist is sufficient to deduce that you know something"* - $\overline{A}B \Rightarrow B$

Again, this is a matter of an implication, but I am not so sure about the "the knowledge that you don't exist is sufficient to deduce that you know something", because $\overline{A}B$ doesn't literally translate to that.

3. *"You exist, unless you don't know anything"* - $\overline{A} \Rightarrow B$

It would have been a normal implication were it not for the word "unless".

Now here comes the hard part. How do I prove that I exist or that I don't exist? I have two ideas:

1.$$(\overline{A}B \Rightarrow \overline{A})(\overline{A}B \Rightarrow B)(A \lor B) \Rightarrow \textbf{A}$$, where I would need to get $\top$ as final result

2.$$(\overline{A}B \Rightarrow \overline{A})(\overline{A}B , \Rightarrow B)(A \lor B) \Rightarrow \overline{\textbf{A}}$$, where I would get $\bot$ as final result.

However, the first one yields $A \lor \overline{B}$, and the second one yields $\overline{A}$.

Can anyone please help? This would be crucial in understanding how this works.

Comment: Are you sure about your 3? The word "unless" implies that if "you don't know anything" is false, then you must exist. In other words $B\implies A$, or $\bar{A}\implies\bar{B}$.

Comment: @Othin you are completely right, that's a misstep on my part. However, even then my idea #1 amounts to $A \lor B$ and idea #2 amounts to $\overline{A}$. I don't get any constant like true or false in either case!

Comment: I'm not sure either. If we let C be the statement "you know you don't exist", then of course $C\implies B \implies A$, which leads to a contradiction. So $C$ can never be true, and this proves that one cannot know that they do not exist. But I don't think this implies $A$ unless there is indeed something you know. Unless we count something like "I know that I couldn't know I don't exist " because I just proved it (which seems strange, and only technically works because the author used the word "you"), then I'm not sure how to finish the proof.

Comment: @Othin since the question was "Does this imply that you exist, or that you don't exist?" Do we really need to get a constant as a final outcome? If I take my second idea into account, is the fact that we only got a single literal as an outcome? It can be both true and false, but if we want the result to be $\top$, we'd need A to be false, from which we conclude that we don't exist. 

I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant in your last comment. Well, there's a small linguistic ambiguity in the question. I take it to mean "Does this imply your existence or does it imply your nonexistence?" meaning the author would want you to prove one of those outcomes (this would require A to be true/false in every interpretation). It could also be read as "Does this imply EITHER of those outcomes?" in which case I believe the answer would be "no" (at least I don't see how it implies any of them without the assumption that the person who is reading knows something).